# How to run .NET Framework 4 on ubuntu

Tags: .net, linux, ubuntu, .net-4.0

I have a project .NET Framework 4 but I don't know how to run it on Ubuntu server.
What .NET Runtime I have to installing to run it? Or do I need install something else?
(P/s: on Windows this is so easy: just click on my file.exe and it's start. How about Ubuntu 20.04?)

Comment: While you *could* try to get Mono up and running, I suspect a better long-term approach would be to port the project to .NET 6.0. It's hard to say more than that without knowing anything about the project though.

Answer (score 0):

.NET Framework 4 can not be run on linux machine. your best bet to upgrade your project to .netcore or even better to .NET 6, both are cross-platform and support Windows, Linux, Mac and more.

Comment: Thank you <3!
I think I've to upgrade my project to .NETcore...

Comment: hey guy! Thank you so much! I just update to .net core 6 and it's working successfully... one more, thank you sooooo muchhhhhh

Answer (score 0):

You can not run .NET Framework applications on ubuntu.
But maybe wine can do it.
Note: The wine looks like Windows 2000!

For installing:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install wine64
wine --version
```

I hope this comment was useful :)

Comment: is this best perfomance for ubuntu? because this project is my server game online!...
thank you!